# Wrong output from Java Calendar API

Tags: java, calendar

**`Calendar.setTimeInMillis`**  and **`Calendar.getTime`**  works weird. It returns incorrect date results.

**Java Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    for(int i=0; i < 30; i++) {
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - i * oneDay);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Tue Jun 24 17:50:35 IST 2014
Mon Jun 23 17:50:35 IST 2014
Sun Jun 22 17:50:35 IST 2014
Sat Jun 21 17:50:35 IST 2014
Fri Jun 20 17:50:35 IST 2014
Thu Jun 19 17:50:35 IST 2014
Wed Jun 18 17:50:35 IST 2014
Tue Jun 17 17:50:35 IST 2014
Mon Jun 16 17:50:35 IST 2014
Sun Jun 15 17:50:35 IST 2014
Sat Jun 14 17:50:35 IST 2014
Fri Jun 13 17:50:35 IST 2014
Thu Jun 12 17:50:35 IST 2014
Wed Jun 11 17:50:35 IST 2014
Tue Jun 10 17:50:35 IST 2014
Mon Jun 09 17:50:35 IST 2014
Sun Jun 08 17:50:35 IST 2014
Sat Jun 07 17:50:35 IST 2014
Fri Jun 06 17:50:35 IST 2014
Thu Jun 05 17:50:35 IST 2014
Wed Jun 04 17:50:35 IST 2014
Tue Jun 03 17:50:35 IST 2014
Mon Jun 02 17:50:35 IST 2014
Sun Jun 01 17:50:35 IST 2014
Sat May 31 17:50:35 IST 2014
Sat Jul 19 10:53:23 IST 2014
Fri Jul 18 10:53:23 IST 2014
Thu Jul 17 10:53:23 IST 2014
Wed Jul 16 10:53:23 IST 2014
Tue Jul 15 10:53:23 IST 2014
```

After "May 31" , It would be "May 30 , May 29 , May 28 & May 27" but it returns incorrect date.

```
    Sat May 31 17:50:35 IST 2014
    Sat Jul 19 10:53:23 IST 2014
    Fri Jul 18 10:53:23 IST 2014
    Thu Jul 17 10:53:23 IST 2014
    Wed Jul 16 10:53:23 IST 2014
    Tue Jul 15 10:53:23 IST 2014
```

Is this bug in `Calendar.getTime()`?

Comment: it is the same with gregorian calendar ?

Comment: @frank Calendar.getInstance() returns GregorianCalendar instance only.

Comment: The answers are correct. An even better solution is to use Joda-Time or java.time. `DateTime dayBefore = someDateTime.minusDays(1);` Furthermore, you can set time to first moment of the day by calling `withTimeAtStartOfDay()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not a bug in `Calendar.getTime()`.

You are using `int`, and when the numbers become too big to fit in an `int`, then `i * oneDay` overflows and you get strange results.

Solution: Use `long` instead:

```
final long oneDay = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

(Your code also doesn't take daylight savings into account, at some point you'll see a shift of an hour if your timezone has daylight savings).

Comment: Yes, It works fine. My question is it would return wrong result for first iteration itself. Am I right?. Why It behaves randomly?

Comment: It doesn't behave randomly, ofcourse. At some point, when `i` becomes large enough (specifically, when `i` is 25), `i * oneDay` becomes too large to fit in an `int` and [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing integer arithmetic and have overflowed an int. The max value of a (signed) int is 2,147,483,647 (2^31-1). There are 86,400,000 milliseconds in ONE_DAY. On day 25 you reach 2,160,000,000, which is a larger value than can be represented in an int and you overflow into negative numbers.

You can solve this by doing your math with longs instead of ints.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    final long oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    for(int i=0; i < 30; i++) {
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - i * oneDay);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
final int oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

with

```
final long oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```